# Where to put parse.parse.push code?

Tags: parse-platform

I want to develop push notification mobile application using javascript. where should i store below code is it in cloude code or my js file or both?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {Parse.Push.send({  channels: ["blue"],data: {alert: "The Giants won against the Mets 2-3. Test"}}, {  success: function() {response.success("Hello world!"); },error: function(error) {   response.fail("Hello world!");}});});
```

Comment: are my above code correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on you system and design. If you go Parse tutorials section in parse official web site
there are lots of examples and tutorials that you can use.Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: It seems to be correct. Just try on Parse cloud. Put in cloud code and call it via programatically and check the error console.